# What official government document should a pilot check to determine what magnetic north a VOR was set to when it was commissioned?

Tags: vor, navaids, magnetic-variation

Today I learned that VOR stations are all set to magnetic north at the time of commission, and since magnetic north moves, the VOR is not necessarily in-line with magnetic north in the present.

Where can a pilot look to read *numerically* what the VOR is set to as its magnetic north?  I understand a sectional chart could be measured, but I want to know where I can read the setting in a manual.

For example, is it contained in chart supplements?

Comment: Are you asking about the FAA?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [chart supplement](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/digital_products/dafd/) does list the magnetic variation of the VORs. Looking under the "radio aids to navigation" section for a nearby airport, it's listed at the end of the line, right after the elevation.

> BATTLE GROUND (H) VORTACW 116.6 BTG Chan 113 N45º44.87´ W122º35.49´
>   160º 9.6 NM to fld. 253/**21E.**

Another source is the [radio fix and holding data records](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/aero_data/Radio_Fix_Holding_8260/) from the FAA. Among other information, you can find the magnetic variation in the remarks section, along with the year it was set.

> REMARKS:
>   ...
>   BTG MAG VAR 1975/E21

---

It's not official, but the easiest place I've found to get this is to search for the navaid on [AirNav](http://airnav.com).